# what's wrong with this sort function? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to find out the index of the element which is the lowest number in the array.
For ex: function getIndexToIns([3, 2, 10, 7], 4) will return 2 because if 4 is inserted into the array, the array should be [2, 3, 4, 7, 10] following ascending order. And 4 has the index of 2.

And my code snippet is as below and it shows error "TypeError: newArr.sort is not a function"

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
newArr = arr.push(num);
newArr.sort((a, b) => a-b);
return newArr.indexOf(num)
}

getIndexToIns([2, 10, 4], 50);
console.log(getIndexToIns([2, 10, 4], 50))
```

What is wrong in my code snippet???

Comment: [arr.push(num)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns a number, not an array

Comment: The task you're trying to solve doesn't seem to require sorting at all. You can just count how many items of the array are less than `num`. That will be the index of `num` if it's inserted ordered. Of `[3, 2, 10, 7]` there are two items less than `4`. The index is thus `2`.

Comment: I figured. Thank you all so much!  :))

Answer (score 1):

`.push()` modifies the array *in place*, it does not return a new array.  So `newArray` isn't an array.

You can create a new array with something like:

```
let newArr = [...arr, num];
```

Or perhaps:

```
let newArr = arr.concat([num]);
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap `num` in an array to `concat()`. Also, it wouldn't need to return a new array (if it returned an array at all), it could return the same array (as Map.set() returns the Map after setting), but the main point is it returns the new length of the array after pushing.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

Remove newArr in `newArr = arr.push(num);` to become

```
arr.push(num);
```

Push method doesn't return the array itself but the new length. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: This is unacceptable because it will modify the original array.

Comment: @MaxScherban I don't see anything in the question that says the array shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @MaksymShcherban This is up to the developer if he wishes to modify the array or not. Agree that this is not fully the whole answer, I only point out the main reason why he has a `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
> returns the new length of the array.

On top of that, `push` and `sort` methods mutate your original array. You should define your `newArr` like this:

```js
const newArr = [...arr, num];
```

Then you can sort it and find out the index of element like you do it now.